# high cpu linked to unresponsive websites?

Tags: cpu, webserver

I have two websites on an ubuntu server. None of them are responding when I try to access them on a browser. So I sshed into my ubuntu server and ran the top command. I noticed that three processes are constantly using 98% CPU:

```
28395 guarddog  20   0  2320  536  424 R  98.0  0.0  17564:52 k                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
28381 guarddog  20   0  2320  388  276 R  97.7  0.0  19483:56 k                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
30762 guarddog  20   0 10640  724  576 R  97.0  0.0  19439:21 ka
10950 guarddog  20   0 3049m 2.1g 4324 S  21.8 36.4  31791:33 ruby
```

I am not sure what "k" and "ka" are. Should I kill these processes? Could this be the reason why the sites do not respond on the browser? I also see that ruby process is using 36.4 percent memory.

Here is output of uptime as well:

```
uptime
 19:10:58 up 173 days,  3:09,  1 user,  load average: 3.94, 4.14, 4.23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't installed anything important that spawns `k` and `ka`, it should be a safe bet to kill them:

```
sudo killall -KILL k; sudo killall -KILL ka
```

Comment: I have no clue if anything important spawned those. Would finding the parent pid lend any clue?

Comment: And what about my load avaerage isn't that really high?

Comment: What is k and ka?

Comment: @JohnMerlino Let's put it this way: If you haven't severely modified your Ubuntu installation, you ought to be fine. At times when your load average isn't too high, you don't have to do this (ie: only use the above line whenever your load gets too high). Also, I didn't really find much for `k` and `ka`, sorry.

Comment: ok so you saying the load isn't too high, but what about those 3 processes taking up 98 percent CPU usage? Won't that have an effect on performance????

Comment: Not exactly what I meant to get across. What I meant is that you can kill those processes if the load gets high (ie: they take up a lot of CPU).